# Can't catch Ldap_add exception

Tags: php, symfony, ldap

I am using LDAP for the first time, along with PHP / symfony: I successfully connect to the LDAP server, and can search and add users/groups, no big issue.
However, when I try to add a user that already exists, I get the following warning:

> HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
>
> Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Already exists

I would like to catch it, since it throws an exception, and could be replaced by a simple toast "Failure: CN is already in use" for the user.

However, I can't find a way to do so, and do not understand why symfony raises such an exception where ldap_add should only return "false" on failure. (It indeed returns true on success): [ldap_add manual](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.ldap-add.php)

EDIT: Here is the incriminated code. Options are fine, the request is successful when I create a new user.

I tried several methods to catch the error, but it seems impossible to catch a warning

```php
    try {
    $result = ldap_add($ldapconn, $userdn, $user);
    } catch(Throwable  $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Sure, it's updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Symfony transforms warning to exceptions... **Only in development environment**

This is a clever choice that avoids your production to explode in case an unexpected behavior occurs in production.

In case of error, **the ldap_add function will return false**. That's what you should check. You may want to entirely shutdown the warning, you can do it by using `@ldap_add` instead.

That said, there are 2 alternatives here.

1. You may want to use a PHP Safe library, it converts warning to exceptions. Here is an example: https://github.com/thecodingmachine/safe
2. You can also temporarily set your own error listener that will throw an exception, actually sometimes Symfony does it in its own codebase. And here is an example: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/27d84dbe57ce65203b26232b87e6660fdba2f30e/src/Symfony/Component/String/AbstractString.php#L509 The most important thing is to not avoid to restore the original error handler.

I hope I helpt!